# SQL 'LIKE' not returning records when there are many matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM CIUploads WHERE UploadTitle LIKE 'example'
```

Snapshot of the CIUploads Table:
[image]

Error, I'm expecting 20+ matches

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took
>   0.0002 sec )

Comment: Use `LIKE '%example%'`. Otherwise your query would be the same as `WHERE UploadTitle = 'example'`

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed the issue, I thought = meant 'Equal to' and LIKE meant 'like' or 'similar to'

Comment: SELECT * FROM CIUploads WHERE UploadTitle LIKE '%example%'

Answer (score 3):

In order to get all records containing the word **example** in `UploadTitle` ,  enclose the word within the wildcard `%` like,

```
SELECT * FROM CIUploads WHERE UploadTitle LIKE '%example%'
```

Adding `LIKE 'example'` (without wildcard) will return records which contain `UploadTitle` as value `example` only. In your table there are other words along with `example` (eg: Video Example) and there are no records containing value exactly as `example`. So it will return empty records.

For more details please refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).

Answer (score 1):

To find records that :
**starts with**   `a   => 'a%'` 
**ends with**     `b   => '%b'`
**containing**    `xyz => '%xyz%'`

Answer (score 1):

Some basics about LIKE -

% Wildcard - means **anything** can replace the % (can be a sentence)

```
WHERE UploadTitle like '%example' --The string ends with example
WHERE UploadTitle like 'example%' --The string starts with example
WHERE UploadTitle like '%example%' --The string contains example
WHERE UploadTitle like 'example' --The string equals to example
```

_ Wildcard - means any **letter** can replace the _ (only 1 letter)

```
WHERE UploadTitle like '__example' --the string has 2 letters before example
WHERE UploadTitle like 'example__' --the string has 2 letters after example
WHERE UploadTitle like '__example__' --the string has 2 letters before  and after example
```

When no wildcard mentioned, it will be recognized as a string and will search for an exact match, so basically it equals to =

```
WHERE UploadTitle like 'example'
```

Same as:

```
WHERE UploadTitle = 'example'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're expecting the given rows (UploadId 57, 58 ...) in the result set.
So you should check whether or not you use a collation with case sensitivity.

If you are using a case sensitive collation, the correct query is

```
SELECT * FROM CIUploads WHERE UploadTitle LIKE '%Example%'
```

(with uppercase 'E' at the beginning of 'Example')